# Search Core Data's Relationships

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

Lets say I have a "Department", "Manager", and "Employee" `NSManagedObjects`.  Lets also say all relationships are many-many.

I want to be able to search for all Employee's that are in Department shoes and under Manager Bob.

How would I word that `NSPredicate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming entity `Department` and `Manager` have a property `name` respectively and the many-many relationship names are the plural forms of the entities try

```
let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Employee")
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "managers.name == 'Bob' && departments.name == 'shoes'")
```

Comment: Yep, I think that checks out.  I realize now that I presented the question incorrectly.